# What is the minimum acceptible value for Idle Time-out(minutes) in IIS?

Tags: iis, iis-express, appdomain, application-pool

Default value for Idle Time-out(minutes) is 20. I changed it to 2 minutes but my app domain is not getting unloaded even if I don't make any request for 3 minutes. Is there any limit for minimum value of Idle Time-out.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a public facing website many things could be requesting it even if you are not. That is a bad test. We set it at zero so it never gets unloaded, no real point in recycling for modern apps unless you have a known memory leak.

Comment: No Wyatt, it is not public facing website. I did it in my development environment to see how app domain gets unloaded after exceeding the idle time-out but  it is not happening.

Comment: Gotcha. Looking at the tags -- are you running it in IIS express or normal IIS?

Comment: It is running in iis. Is there any difference between iis express and iis in dealing with idle time out?

Comment: Not sure if IIS express honors that at all to be honest. IIS should but as you can see it isn't perfect.